# Что такое связь 0:N?

Tags: mysql, связи

Что обозначает связь 0:N ?

Дали задание и есть пункт "один продукт может принадлежать к 0:N категорий"
Это один ко многим? Один продукт может иметь много категорий?

Comment: *Что обозначает связь 0:N ?* На самом деле так обозначают связь (0 или 1):N. Это когда поле связи на стороне "много" может быть NULL, т.е. не связано с записью на стороне "один".

Comment: @Akina значит как написали в ответе это связь один ко многим?

Comment: А вот этого я сказать не могу. На то и угадайка, что надо не указывать правильный ответ, а угадывать, какой ответ автор теста считает правильным.

Comment: Больше похоже на многие ко многим. Один ко многим может быть теоретически с гулом, но на практике нет в этом смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Связь один-ко-многим. Верно, один продукт может содержать от 0 до N категорий.

Comment: Наверное, всё же, не *"содержать"*, а *"принадлежать к"*. // минус не мой, если что

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/514648)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor позвольте не согласиться. Данный ответ как раз таки отвечает на вопрос ТС - "Что такое связь 0:N?", пускай и неправильно, но удалять его не стоит - это валидный ответ.

Comment: @Kromster ok...